# When a QGraphicsItem is deleted will it be removed from the QGraphicsItemGroup automatically?

Tags: qt

If I add a QGraphicsItem to a QGraphicsItemGroup,
then later I delete that QGraphicsItem, will it be automatically removed from the QGraphicsItemGroup?

Comment: I think it will but you can easily test for yourself, can't you.

Comment: Emm...Actually I don't know how to test this. There is even no size() function for the QGraphicsItemGroup. How could I check its content?

Comment: maybe by checking the bounding rect. in theory the bounding rect would be something different than the removed item. Or by drawing the group, it should explode when a still contained item is already deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from [1](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#dtor.QGraphicsItem) and [2](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setParentItem) it should be removed from the group.

Print out group.childItems().
Before deleteing the item from the group it should be contained in there.
After deleting the item it should not be.

You can probably also test this by checking the bounding box of the group after deleting the item, or by drawing the group and see if the item is drawn or the program explodes.